# php SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following error when I go to view.php: {"success":0,"message":"SQLSTATE[3D000]: Invalid catalog name: 1046 No database selected"}, can someone help to solve this issue?

My code is this:

db_connect.php

```
<?php
class Operations{
    private $db_host = "localhost";
    private $db_name = "supplierInquiry";

        public function dbConnection()
        {
            try {
                $conn = new PDO('mysql:host=' . $this->db_host . ';dbName=' . $this->db_name);
                    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
                return $conn;
            } catch (PDOException $e) {
                echo "Connection error " . $e->getMessage();
                exit;
            }
        }
}
?>
```

in the view.php the code is:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ERROR);
header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Headers: access");
header("Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET");
header("Content-Type: application/json; charset=UTF-8");

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] !== 'GET') :
    http_response_code(405);
    echo json_encode([
        'success'=>0,
        'message'=>'Bad Request Detected! Only get method is allowed',
    ]);
    exit;
endif;

require 'db_connect.php';
$database = new Operations();
$conn = $database->dbConnection();

if (isset($_GET['id'])) {
    $suppliers_id = filter_var($_GET['id'], FILTER_VALIDATE_INT, [
        'options' => [
            'default' => 'all_suppliers',
            'min_range' => 1
        ]
    ]);
}

try {
    $sql = is_numeric($suppliers_id) ? "SELECT * FROM `supplier` WHERE id='$suppliers_id'" : "SELECT * FROM `supplier`";
    $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

    $stmt->execute();

    if ($stmt->rowCount() > 0) : 

        $data = null;

        if (is_numeric($suppliers_id)) {
            $data = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        } else { 
            $data = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
        }

        echo json_encode([
            'success' => 1,
            'data' => $data,
        ]);

        else : 
        echo json_encode([
            'success' => 0,
            'message' => 'No Record Found!',
        ]);
    endif;
    }
// The error is from this catch 
catch (PDOException $e) {
    http_response_code(500);
    echo json_encode([     
        'success' => 0,
        'message' => $e->getMessage()
    ]);
    exit;
    }

?>
```

[image: An this is my database]

This is the video tutorial from where I'm learning https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5huuXugiVNU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The MySQL DSN you are using has a typo: it should be `dbname` and not `dbName`

Tested in https://extendsclass.com/php-bin/8c2096d